# Please identify this tree in the Netherlands

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image: tree and flower]

Please identify this tree for me. It was found in a park in Eindhoven, Netherlands.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is a hazel (*Corylus avellana*) based on:

- the leaves
- the male flowers (not mature in your photo)
- the fact that it is a common tree in Europe)

This one has twisty branches, so it could well be of a particular variety called "contorta".

According to 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corylus_avellana#Cultivation_and_uses

> A selection with twisted branches has been propagated horticulturally as Corylus avellana 'Contorta'.

Comment: Though providing links to supporting sources is ideal and often required when answering [tag:species-identification] questions, citing random non-reputable links is harmful to constructive learning and often inaccurate. This is *especially* true of google search results, which are *very* often inaccurate.  Please do the extra homework and find an image or description from a *reputable* source. (e.g., [here](http://www.hort.uconn.edu/plants/detail.php?pid=132) or [here](https://www.keele.ac.uk/arboretum/trees/species/hazel/)). Thanks!

Comment: @theforestecologist Sorry for the link. I thought it would improve my answer because the male flowers in the wikipedia article or the link you suggest are mature ones. I removed it. Feel free to edit my post or propose another better documented answer.

Comment: Well, you don't have to remove the link necessarily, but use it as cautionary evidence instead of direct evidence. If that makes sense....In general, though, if your best line of evidence is a link such as one from google images, it probably just means you need to keep searching for better evidence. So, keep the link if you'd like (with some note signifying its lack of reputability), but take the time to keep searching for better support :). Thanks!